# Installing Active Directory and internet connectivity

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, dhcp

After installing Active Directory on our new server (Windows Server 2008 R2) following [these requirements](http://www.petri.co.il/active-directory-windows-server-2008-requirements.htm) we lost internet connectivity on the server itself.

How can we restore it? Using the second NIC available?

Thanks.

Comment: How is the server's DNS configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very like a DNS issue, or possibly a routing one - can you ping remote hosts by IP?  64.34.119.12 (www.serverfault.com), for example?

As the linked article mentions, the new DC will be its own primary DNS server, so it will be able to see all the resource records that AD sticks into DNS.  Unless you've got a forwarder configured to handle requests for things that aren't in your local DNS, you will indeed lose Internet connectivity.

Comment: No unfortunately I cannot ping both IP and domain name. What should I check?

Comment: Check the server's TCP/IP config, especially the DNS servers and default gateway; can you ping other machines on your LAN from the server?

Also, you may want to check the DNS console (as opposed to the NIC settings) on the server.

Comment: I agree with @RainyRat that this sounds an awful lot like a DNS configuration issue. Have you checked that you have a forwarder configured? Is your server pointing to itself for primary DNS?

Comment: I followed this tutorial http://www.petri.co.il/installing-active-directory-windows-server-2008.htm for active directory installation  but it looks like there is something missing. I also configured IPv4 as specified in these prerequisites: http://www.petri.co.il/active-directory-windows-server-2008-requirements.htm. Why I cannot ping 192.168.101.1 from client machines?

Comment: The tutorial gets you to configure your server as 192.168.101.1; do your clients also have IP addresses in the same range?  Also, the tutorial makes no mention of setting a default gateway, which you'll probably need in order to connect to the Internet, or anything else outside your 192.168.101.0 subnet.

Comment: Thanks RR: The machine I am working on has DHCP enabled and IP 192.168.1.18, should I change something?

Comment: Yes, that would explain it!  You'll need to adjust your DHCP server to hand out addresses in the 192.168.101.* range; then they'll be on the same subnet as the server and will be able to see it.  While you're adjusting DHCP, you could also get it to push out the server's IP as the clients' primary DNS server.  You'll still need to give the server a default gateway, thought, if you want Internet access.

Comment: RR: Probably I need to solve first the ping issue, then the internet connectivity one. Isn't more convenient to change 192.168.101.1 to 192.168.1.1? All the clients (Ethernet printed included) are in this range...

Comment: Yes, that would work too.